Transform: rotate on hover not working on mobile versions of safari and web apps
The transform rotate on hover CSS function works perfectly on desktop versions of web browsers and chrome mobile. But I cannot get it to rotate when clicked / tapped on, in the mobile safari and app web browsers like Instagram. I have tried plugging my iphone to my macbook to debug but have no idea what else to do.
my entire HTML
<section>

  <div class="left">

    <h1> Rebelz <br>
    
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="middle">
    
    <div class="scroll">
      
     <div class="hi img0"> </div>
    <div class="hi img1"> </div>
    <div class="hi img2"> </div>
    <div class="hi img3"> </div>
    <div class="hi img4"> </div>
     <div class="hi img5"> </div>
      <div class="hi img0"> </div>
       <div class="hi img1"> </div>
      
  </div>
     </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="hi2"> </div>

  </div>

</section>

CSS
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out; 
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); 
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

Mobile
/*mobile */

@media (max-width: 950px) {
  
  h1 {
  font-size: 20vw;
}
  section {
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg); 
    transform: rotate(4deg);
  }
    
  div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); 
    transform: rotate(10deg); }
  
  .middle{
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  .left {
    position: relative;
  }  
}

Website and codepen
This is the particular code I am having difficulties with.
I've tried debugging the website on ios not sure what or how to approach this issue
